# CUDA memory Error when using NAMD, mentions cygwin even though cygwin isn't installed?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry, high-performance-computing, graphical-processing-unit

I've run into some issues with NAMD that cause me to get the following error whenever I try to begin a simulation run:

```
namd2 +idlepoll minimization.namd > minimization.log
```

I get:

```
FATAL ERROR: CUDA error cudaMalloc(pp, sizeofT*(*curlen)) in file C:\cygwin64\usr\tmp\NAMD-build-2020-Aug-05-31699-Win64-CUDA\namd2\src\CudaUtils.C, function reallocate_device_T, line 130 on Pe 0 (roshan device 0 pci 0:1:0): out of memory
```

So far, what led to this happening was that my NAMD installation was previously functional, but after installing and seemingly uninstalling Cygwin on my Windows machine I started getting this error. I then reset and wiped my PC completely and reinstalled Windows, but the error persists.

If anyone else has gotten this error or solved this problem, I'd greatly appreciate the help. Thank you so much!

Comment: How is the Windows executable compiled? Is it possible that it uses cygwin?

Comment: Two questions - 1) did you install NAMD from the official website (i.e. the zip file), 2) did you have an installation of CUDA drivers in cygwin?